# How can I update, delete, insert to the admin store in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I was wondering if there is a way to update the Admin store in react-admin. I am using web-sockets to get data from my server for example if the record was updated or a new one was created - I could either add it to the resource or update the resource.

I know one of the ways I can do is useDataProvider and then fetch the record from the server to update or insert. But not sure if I should be doing that when the websocket already has the data.

I have created extra stores and can modify them by dispatching actions but not sure how I can do that with the admin store without making an unnecessary call to the server.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can save data from WebSocket to storage by yourself forming a Redux action similar to what DataProvider uses.